# By using like operator How to search text which is concatenated columns values

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-like, calculated-columns, cakephp-2.x

I am developing application with cakephp ,in my code i am developing search functionality.i have table with number fields . i want to search data which is concatenation of 3 columns values.but problem here it is in one column has id of value other two columns directly have data.now i want to split search data ,and get first value id  from other tables and search whole data.

example i want to search `ab/c001/2019`, in this i stored `c001` and `2019` in same table but ab  i am storing id of that value which is getting from another table.
i tried with get full search value and used like operator to search.

in  value `ab/c001/2019` i want to replace ab with other variable dynamically.means string before first slash replace with one variable which i am getting dynamically

Comment: Use [Search plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) - this makes your code so much easier, more reliable and future proof.

Comment: ok mark i am getting this result .from this result how to get id and assign this in a variable Array
(
    [GroupValue] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23006
        )

)

Comment: I got that id but those values i want to concatenate to anothe value in table